# Draw android xml shape diagonal with triangles

Tags: android, xml, shapes, diagonal

Hi I would like to draw something like this

[image: Diagonal]

with a shape Is it possible ?

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: I tried two rectangles and rotate them, but I have no experience with drawing xml shapes ..

Comment: why you dot try with images

Comment: I need then add corner radius 5 dp something like this:`<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/button_buy_pre" />
</shape>`

Answer (score 7):

I know its too late to answer this question but still posting my answer here so that others can have reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:height="100dp"
android:width="100dp"
android:viewportHeight="100"
android:viewportWidth="100">

<path
    android:name="dark_triangle"
    android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:pathData="M 100,0 L 0,100 100,100 z" />

<path
    android:name="light_triangle"
    android:fillColor="#d0021b"
    android:pathData="M 0,0 L 100,0 0,100 z" />

</vector>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the best answer.

Comment: The most concise answer ever! I need to take a crash course on creating vector graphics in Android!

Answer (score 5):

**@Pauli** .You can use Image for easy practice and can try this way . Use this logic

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:drawable="@color/Your_color">
</item>

<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="50"
        android:pivotX="10%"
        android:pivotY="85%"
         >
        <shape

            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />

        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

**SO Courtesy**

> [Diagonally spilliting background of a Relative Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382269/diagonally-spilliting-background-of-a-relative-layout)
>
> [Making a triangle shape using xml definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517589/making-a-triangle-shape-using-xml-definitions)

Comment: I have seen this links before and tried it.. but it's not what I'm looking

Answer (score 4):

1. Create color resources in colors.xml file

   ```
   <color name="primaryColor">#3F51B5</color>
   <color name="primaryColorDark">#303F9F</color>
   ```
2. Create Java file TriangleBackgroundView.Java:

   ```
   public class TriangleBackgroundView extends View {
   Paint paint;
   Paint bgPaint;

   public TriangleBackgroundView(Context context) {
       super(context);
       init();
   }

   public TriangleBackgroundView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       init();
   }

   public TriangleBackgroundView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
       init();
   }

   private void init() {
       paint = new Paint();
       paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
       paint.setAntiAlias(true);
       paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
       paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
       paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));

       bgPaint= new Paint();
       bgPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
       bgPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColorDark));
   }

   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
       super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.onDraw(canvas);

       int h = getMeasuredHeight();
       int w = getMeasuredWidth();

       canvas.drawRect(0,0,w,h,bgPaint);

       Path path = new Path();
       path.moveTo(0, h);
       path.lineTo(w, h);
       path.lineTo(0, 0);
       path.lineTo(0, h);
       path.close();
       canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
   }
   }
   ```
3. Now add custom view in your layout:

```
<com.yourpackage.TriangleBackgroundView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

You can get help from this tutorial to create shape diagonal with triangle:

Source: http://marcouberti.net/2015/06/23/create-a-custom-triangle-background-view-in-android/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11054400)

Comment: Edited the post @AbhinavSinghMaurya

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/yellow_color"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="85%"
            android:pivotY="135%">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@color/brown_color" />

            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-35%"
            android:pivotY="85%">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/brown_color" />

            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The two rotated rectangles do the work of fill brown side in your image.

Answer (score 1):

half_diagonal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">

    <path
        android:name="dark_triangle"
        android:fillColor="#673AB7"
        android:pathData="M 0,0 L 100,0 0,100 z" />

</vector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gradient tool...

http://angrytools.com/gradient/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(192,192,192,1) 0%, rgba(192,192,192,1) 49%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* ff3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(192,192,192,1)), color-stop(49%, rgba(192,192,192,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* safari4+,chrome */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(192,192,192,1) 0%, rgba(192,192,192,1) 49%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* safari5.1+,chrome10+ */